# Issues outputting database information if a column has a selected word

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I am attempting to output information from my database, only if the record has 'Pending' in the column 'status' filled in. As of right now this is breaking and I have multiple records with 'Pending' filled in, in that column.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $pending_id = $row['status'];
                if($pending_id == ["Pending"]){
                    $pending_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                    $pending_lastname = $row['lastname'];
                    $pending_username = $row['username'];
                }
        }
    }
                echo $pending_firstname;
?>
```

UPDATE:

I only get the first result with this...

```
if( $numrows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $pending_id = $row['status'];
                if($pending_id == "Pending"){
                    $pending_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                    $pending_lastname = $row['lastname'];
                    $pending_username = $row['username'];
                }
        }
    }
    if ($pending_firstname == true) {
                    echo $pending_firstname;
                } else {
                    echo "There are no Pending Requests as this time.";
                }
  ?>
```

Comment: It's only defined when the `while` and `if` block were run. Also the comparison `$pending_id == ["Pending"]` would at best compare a string against an array. Why btw, not codify that filter in the SQL query?

Comment: What do toy mean "Why btw, not codify that filter in the SQL query?'

Comment: Such as `WHERE status = 'Pending'`

Comment: Gotcha. Because I am going to be doing something similar to this.... `$pending_id = $row['status'];
                    if($pending_id == "Pending"){` ...........  `$pending_id = $row['status'];
                    if($pending_id == "Approved"){` .........`$pending_id = $row['status'];
                    if($pending_id == "Denied"){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to put a string in square brackets to match against it.

```
if($pending_id == "Pending")...
```

OK - Try this code..
You need to output your user details INSIDE your loop, or they will be over-written

```
if( $numrows ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){            
        if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

            $pending_id        = $row['user_id'];
            $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
            $pending_username  = $row['username'];

            echo "$pending_firstname $pending_lastname $pending_username <br>";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally had that, but changed it to see if it would help. I no longer get the undefined variable notice, but still nothing displays.

Comment: I updated my question. I am only getting the first record to display in my echo even though I have a while loop when I defined the variable?

Answer (score 1):

look you declare `pending_firstname` and also all variables into if statement under a while and under another if statement. and you are echoing `pending_firstname` outside it's scope. that's why you are getting this error. to avoid this first declare all the variables in a global scope then you can access them from anywhere. and it's a good practice also!

**UPDATE**

actually you should declare all of your variable as an array. and using a `array_push()` method you can push more than one data into that array and you can iterate over those array using a `foreach` in the future.

Comment: I updated my question. I am only getting the first record to display in my echo even though I have a while loop when I defined the variable?

Comment: sorry for late, i'm seeing your problem has been solved. actually you should declare all of your needed variable as an array in the global scope and using `array_push()` method you can push more than one value into the array and in the future you can iterate over them using a `foreach` or whatever

Comment: Could you show me an example of what you mean? I'm not quite sure I'm catching what you are saying?